# Can't run demo code: Bottle class demo

Tags: java, class, methods

So I can't run my demo code. To be honest, I have no idea why it won't run. Any thoughts? i have to follow this demo in order to produce my own code. I'm running the cod in eclipse and the error that comes up is "Bottle cannot be resolved to a type". This message displays about 8 times. The description of the assignment is as follows:

> Write a Bottle class. The class has these 14 methods: read(), set(int), set(Bottle), get(), and(Bottle), subtract(Bottle), multiply(Bottle), divide(Bottle), add(int), subtract(int), multiply(int), divide(int), equals(Bottle), and toString(). The toString() method will be given in class. All add, subtract, multiply, and divide methods return a Bottle. Your Bottle class must guarantee bottles always have a positive value and never exceed a maximum number chosen by you. These numbers are declared as constants of the class. Each method wit ha parameter must be examined to determine if the upper or lower bound could be violated. Consider each method carefully and test only the conditions that could be violated.

The Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// test driver for the Bottle class
public class BottleDemo3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        Bottle bottle1 = new Bottle();
        Bottle bottle2 = new Bottle();
        Bottle bottle3 = new Bottle();
        Bottle bottle4 = new Bottle();
        Bottle bottle5 = new Bottle();
        System.out.println("please enter a number for bottle1:");
        bottle1.read();
        System.out.println("Bottle1 is this value " + bottle1 + ".");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for bottle2:");
        bottle2.read();
        bottle3 = bottle3.add(bottle1);
        bottle3 = bottle3.add(bottle2);
        bottle3 = bottle3.divide(2);
        System.out.println("The 2 bottle average is: " + bottle3 + ".");
        System.out.print("Subtracting bottle1 from bottle2 is: " );
        bottle3 = bottle2.subtract(bottle1);
        System.out.println( bottle3);
        bottle3 = bottle2.divide(bottle1);
        System.out.println("Dividing bottle2 with bottle1 is: " + bottle3 + ".");
        if (bottle1.equals(bottle2))
        {
            System.out.println("Bottle1 and bottle2 are equal.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Bottle1 and bottle2 are not equal.");
        }
        System.out.println("Bottle4 is now given the value of 10 with the set() method.");
        bottle4.set(10);
        System.out.println("The value of bottle4 is " + bottle4 + ".");
        System.out.println("Bottle4 is now multipled with bottle1.  The value is placed in " +
                "bottle5.");
        bottle5 = bottle1.multiply(bottle4);
        System.out.println("The value of bottle5 is " + bottle5 + ".");
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to add to the value bottle1 has.");
        System.out.println("The sum will be put in bottle3.");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        bottle3 = bottle1.add(x);
        System.out.println("Adding your number " + x +
            " to bottle1 gives a new Bottle with " + bottle3 + " in it.");
        System.out.print("Adding the number " + bottle2 + " which is the number" +
                " in bottle2 to the\nnumber in ");
        bottle2 = bottle1.add(bottle2);
        System.out.println("bottle1 which is " + bottle1 +" gives " + bottle2 + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include `why the code is not working and what errors,if any,are getting displayed`!

Comment: It says write a Bottle class. Where is your Bottle class?

Comment: I haven't written a bottle class yet. My professor said that the bottle demo should run on its own and play as an example for our own bottle class.

Comment: This code uses a class called Bottle. If there is no Bottle class, it won't run. Perhaps there is a compiled Bottle class, without the source code, that you are supposed to use? Look for a file called "Bootle.class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ,the error clearly suggests that you haven't implemented a Bottle class which you're using in `BottleDemo3` class. Actually,in Java all the classes or methods which we use has to be defined somewhere,either in library form,API, or in custom user-defined classes!

Your BottleDemo3 class is fine,but you need an existing class named `Bottle` with all the mentioned methods like `read(),set(int),set(Bottle)`,etc. already implemented by Bottle class to use it later in BottleDemo3.

So,please prepare a Bottle class before you're to use it in BottleDemo3 class. It should define all the methods so that you can call those methods over Bottle class using Bottle objects!

> My professor said that the bottle demo should run on its own and play
>   as an example for our own bottle class.

Actually,he might have said this because you might be having a Bottle.java class already implemented in your previous project! Kindly import that .java file using import `import packageName.Bottle` in your current project.

if you've still doubts,please ask below...

Comment: Yea, I believe you are right. But I have to write the Bottle class myself. So I have began on that at the moment.

Comment: @user2829552-I love your way of indenting code,which univ. are you studying in?

Comment: Nothern Virginia Community College, And the Demo class isn't mine... It is one that my professor provided for my class.

Comment: @user2829552-Best wishes for your further projects,keep coding happily and you'll enjoy coming on StackOverflow for quesions as well as giving answers once you gain enough background about programming!

Comment: Also, I enrolled into the class about 4 days late... So I have no idea how I'm suppose to create the bottle class haha. I'm screwed!

Comment: @user2829552-Start from basics,you'll be able to cover that within 2-3 hours.Start with learning classes and methods and then you'll be able to shoot high! BEST WISHES..